# No puedo atrapar este error (StackOverFlowException)

Tags: vb.net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En un proyecto que estoy haciendo, tengo este error que no logro localizar.
Es un formulario principal con un TabControl que cargan otros formularios dentro de cada una de sus pestañas.
 ¿A alguién le pasó algo parecido? ¿Alguna idea de que puede generarlo?

-Edito:

Gracias por la respuesta.
Me repite estas tres lineas una y otra vez (Tambien edito imagen):

> MdiTabControl.dll!MdiTabControl.TabControl.TabPageCollection.set_IndexOf(MdiTabControl.TabPage
>   TabPage, Integer value) Línea 287 + 0xd Bytes
>
> MdiTabControl.dll!MdiTabControl.TabControl.SelectItem(MdiTabControl.TabPage
>   TabPage) Línea 1607 + 0x22 Bytes MdiTabControl.dll!
>
> MdiTabControl.TabControl.ArrangeItems() Línea 1532 + 0x46 Bytes

No sé muy bien que intenta hacer el control exactamente. Se produce normalmente al cambiar de pantalla o minimizar, de manera bastante aleatoria (No siempre se produce).
¿Alguna idea de que podria producirlo?¿Cambiar el control por el propio de VS podría solucionarlo?

EDIT2: Estas son las unicas lineas de codigo donde interviene el MDItabcontrol:

```
Public Sub openForm(ByRef frm As Form)
    Try

    TabControl1.Visible = True
        TabControl1.TabPages.Add(frm)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

 Private Sub resizeform(ByVal sender As System.Object)
    Try
    TabControl1.Width = sender.Size.Width - 20
        TabControl1.Height = sender.Size.Height - ToolStrip1.Height - TabControl1.TabHeight
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
    If Me.Visible Then
        resizeform(sender)
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub repintarfondo()
    Try
        If TabControl1.TabPages.Count = 1 Then
            TabControl1.Visible = False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Como podéis ver, no tengo ningún evento para los que se muestran en la imagen. Por eso me extraña tanto.

Un saludo y gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: incluye el código relevante de las lineas que salen en el error o en su defecto si es una clase de una lib/jar, tus lineas que la llamen

Comment: Revisa el código de estos métodos. Si por ejemplo en el evento SelectedItem del TabControl cambias la pestaña activa esto provocaría que vuelva a saltar el evento, y así indefinidamente. Parece que por ahí pueden ir los tiros.

Comment: Editado de nuevo :) Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Es un error de desbordamiento de la pila de llamadas.

Cuando se genera la excepción mira la ventana de pila de llamadas.

Este error se produce cuando se dan operaciones recursivas. Bien un método se está llamando a sí mismo de manera recursiva o está llamando a un método que a su vez llama al método inicial.

Esto provoca que la aplicación entre en un bucle infinito realizando llamadas a este método hasta que llega al límite de sobrepasar el límite de la pila de llamadas y se produce el error.

Como te decía, revisa la ventana de pila de llamadas en el momento en el que se produce el error y podrás ver el o los métodos que están generando el problema.

Comment: Edito arriba :)

Comment: Editado again :) gracias

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow es el típico error de recursividad infinita. En tu caso, hay un claro sospechoso

```
Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged....
    .....
    resizeform(sender)
```

aparentemente estás cambiando el tamaño de un form en el evento de cambio de tamaño de ese form. Me huele a infinitamente recursivo....

Answer (score 0):

`StackOverflowException` es una excepción que no puede ser controlada salvo que sea lanzada por el propio código que estas programando. Lo mas recomendable para estos casos es verificar la pila de ejecución ya que tipicamente sucede cuando se dan bucles de llamadas infinitos, ya sea en funciones recursivas indirecta o directa. Según veo el problema esta en el control MdiTabControl, lo que podrias hacer es descargar el codigo de este, el cual se encuentra en [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16436/A-highly-configurable-MDI-tab-control-from-scratch)
y usarlo como referencia para evaluar con mayor detalle cuales son lo factores que probocan la excepcion